# Weird distorsions in light when using denoise node

Tags: lighting, reflection, denoise, distort

When using the denoising node I happen to have some distortions where the light bounces. When I increase the samples to 600 it's reduced but it still be noticeable.

What may be causing this effect?
[image]
[image]

Comment: Hi :). That's caused by too little samples, 1000+ samples should help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is entirely normal. With too few samples, such as lower than 500 in this case, the denoiser doesn’t have much data to work with, and the result ends up splotchy as it tries to fake information. When more of the pixels are closer to their correct values, the faking is not as obvious.

Comment: So the only solution is to pump up the samples to lets say... 2000?

Comment: @Miki Two thousand should be enough for a whole lot of noise causing render items, but usually I can get away with something like 1024 with ease. 512, now that’s a bit tight but still fine in most cases. 256, pretty tight, but manageable. 128 is absolute minimum for full render IBO.